# How to inner join multiple sum/group queries each with different where clauses?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using `UNION` on the code below results in two columns:

1. `[Operator Company Name]`
2. `Sum(Gross Acres)`

For each `[Operator Company Name]` there are 5 records (rows) due to the 5 queries.

How do I properly write a `UNION` or `JOIN` where the result of each of the 5 queries results in an independent column, and they are then all joined on the `[Operator Company Name]` so that the new query output is 1 record per column and 6 columns (co name + 5 query results)

```
SELECT [Operator Company Name],
Sum([Area (Gross Acres)]) AS [Sum(Gross Acres)]
FROM Enervus_PrivateData
WHERE [US Region] Like 'Permian'
GROUP BY [Operator Company Name];

union

SELECT [Operator Company Name],
Sum([Area (Gross Acres)]) AS [Sum(TX DEL Acres)]
FROM Enervus_PrivateData
WHERE [US Region] Like 'Permian' AND [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Reeves*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Culberson*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Pecos*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Loving*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Ward*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Winkler*'
GROUP BY [Operator Company Name];

union

SELECT [Operator Company Name],
Sum([Area (Gross Acres)]) AS [Sum(N MID Acres)]
FROM Enervus_PrivateData
WHERE [US Region] Like 'Permian' AND [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Dawson*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Borden*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Martin*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Howard*'
GROUP BY [Operator Company Name];

union

SELECT [Operator Company Name],
Sum([Area (Gross Acres)]) AS [Sum(NM DEL Acres)]
FROM Enervus_PrivateData
WHERE [US Region] Like 'Permian' AND [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Eddy*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Lea*'
GROUP BY [Operator Company Name];

union

SELECT [Operator Company Name],
Sum([Area (Gross Acres)]) AS [Sum(S MID Acres)]
FROM Enervus_PrivateData
WHERE [US Region] Like 'Permian' AND [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Midland*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Glasscock*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Upton*' OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Reagan*'
GROUP BY [Operator Company Name];
```

The actual results should include 1 record per column with the columns

1. `[Operator Company Name]` - where all the queries are joined by
2. `[Sum(Gross Acres)]`
3. `[Sum(TX DEL Acres)]`
4. `[Sum(N MID Acres)]`
5. `[Sum(NM DEL Acres)]`
6. `[Sum(S MID Acres)]`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adress this using *conditional aggregation*.

The trick consists in using a `IIF` statement in each `SUM()` that holds the condition from the corresponding original subquery. If conditions are met, then the value should be taken into account in the `SUM`, else it should be ignored.

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    [Operator Company Name],
    Sum([Area (Gross Acres)]) AS [Sum(Gross Acres)],
    Sum(
        IIF( 
            (
                [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Reeves*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Culberson*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Pecos*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Loving*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Ward*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Winkler*'
            ), 
            [Area (Gross Acres)],
            0
        )
    ) AS [Sum(TX DEL Acres)],
    Sum(
        IIF(
            (
                [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Dawson*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Borden*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Martin*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Howard*'
            ),
            [Area (Gross Acres)],
            0
        )
    ) AS [Sum(N MID Acres)],
    Sum(
        IIF(
            (
                [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Eddy*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Lea*'
            ),
            [Area (Gross Acres)],
            0
        )
    ) AS [Sum(NM DEL Acres)],
    Sum(
        IIF(
            (
                [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Midland*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Glasscock*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Upton*' 
                OR [COUNTY/PARISH] Like '*Reagan*'
            ),
            [Area (Gross Acres)],
            0
        )
    ) AS [Sum(S MID Acres)]
FROM Enervus_PrivateData
WHERE [US Region] Like 'Permian'
GROUP BY [Operator Company Name];
```